# Edit box SetWindowText breaking the box

Tags: c++, winapi

(sorry about the length)
   The problem I am having is the specifically with the SetWindowText function on the text box controls. I have it set up so when I press the "Shoot" button it grabs what is in the text boxes, checks its input, and if valid it throws it in some variables for the game to run with. Everything works fine, except whenever I use the SetWindowText on one of the text boxes (I'm trying to get the text box to clear its text when you click on it) it will clear the text but then any input I do to it afterward crashes the program as well as if I just exit the program it exits with an error. The error usually looks like:

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x77CE220F (ntdll.dll) in Physics Project 0.3 Cleaned Up.exe:     0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00060FB4."
```

Although sometimes where it says "ntdll.dll" it says "kernel.dll" or "user32.dll"
   Also a common break point it jumps to is in the string header file and the code it breaks at reads

```
const value_type *_Myptr() const
        {   // determine current pointer to buffer for nonmutable string
        return (this->_BUF_SIZE <= this->_Myres
            ? _STD addressof(*this->_Bx._Ptr)
            : this->_Bx._Buf);
        }
```

I tried using both a string and a char array to try and avoid the nonmutable string as well as just inserting a TEXT( "" ) directly into the SetWindowText call but nothing works

I am doing this project as an honors project for my C++ class so I have taught myself everything in this project from Win32 and DirectX so I apologize if there is a pretty obvious mistake. Along with the error, I would like to know about cleaning up the memory that is allocated for the windows on exit. I have at the end of WinMain a set of ZeroMemory calls for all the windows I created because it feels weird to end the program without cleaning up the memory but I don't really see other people have those so let me know if that is unneeded or if there is a different way of doing it.

Code I have the problem with:

```
using namespace std;

///////////////////// Window/Control Handles ////////////////////
HWND hButton;               // Shoot button
HWND hTextBoxVeloc;         // Velocity Entry Field
HWND hTextBoxAngle;         // Angle Entry Field

enum ControlList { ID_BUTTON, ID_VELOC_TB, ID_ANGLE_TB };

////////////////////// User Input Variables /////////////////////
int   getTextWinState;
char  velocEntered[ENTRY_SIZE];
float userVeloc;
char  angleEntered[ENTRY_SIZE];
float userAngle;
bool  hButtonClicked = false;

short  troopDist;
string troopDistStr;
const short TEN = 10;

//***************************************************************
//string blankBox = "";
//char blankBox[1];
//***************************************************************


/////////////////////////// Prototypes //////////////////////////
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
string TroopDistToString(void);


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine,
               INT)
{
// Game Window Class
WNDCLASSEX wc;

ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = ( (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW );
wc.lpszClassName = "Game Window";

RegisterClassEx(&wc);
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow( "Game Window", "Projectile Motion",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
                          0,  0,
                          CLIENT_WIN_WIDTH, CLIENT_WIN_HEIGHT,
                          NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );


ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
UpdateWindow(hWnd);
Game theGame(hWnd);


MSG msg;
ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof(msg) );

while(TRUE)
{
    while( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        break;

    theGame.Run();
}

UnregisterClass( "Game Window", wc.hInstance );

//////////////////////// Possibly unneeded /////////////////////////
ZeroMemory( &hStaticTxtBoxDistance, sizeof(hStaticTxtBoxDistance) );
ZeroMemory( &hStaticTxtBoxAngleCap, sizeof(hStaticTxtBoxAngleCap) );
ZeroMemory( &hTextBoxAngle,         sizeof(hTextBoxAngle)         );
ZeroMemory( &hStaticTxtBoxVelocCap, sizeof(hStaticTxtBoxVelocCap) );
ZeroMemory( &hTextBoxVeloc,         sizeof(hTextBoxVeloc)         );
ZeroMemory( &hButton,               sizeof(hButton)               );
ZeroMemory( &wc,                    sizeof(wc)                    );
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
HDC hdcStatic = ( (HDC)wParam );
HBRUSH hbrBkgnd = NULL;
switch(message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
    /////////////////////////////////// Take Shot Controls //////////////////////////////////

    // Take Shot Button
    hButton = CreateWindow( "Button", "Take Shot",
                            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                            CONTROL_START_X, 10, 
                            CONTROL_WIDTH, CONTROL_HEIGHT,
                            hWnd, ( (HMENU)ID_BUTTON ), NULL, NULL );

    /////////////////////////////////// Velocity Controls ///////////////////////////////////

    // Velocity Textbox
    hTextBoxVeloc = CreateWindow( "Edit", blankBox.c_str(),
                                  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                                  CONTROL_START_X, VELOC_TB_START_Y, 
                                  CONTROL_WIDTH, CONTROL_HEIGHT,
                                  hWnd, ( (HMENU)ID_VELOC_TB ), NULL, NULL );

    //////////////////////////////////// Angle Controls /////////////////////////////////////

    // Angle Textbox
    hTextBoxAngle = CreateWindow(  "Edit", "Angle TB" ,
                                  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                                  CONTROL_START_X, ANGLE_TB_START_Y, 
                                  CONTROL_WIDTH, CONTROL_HEIGHT,
                                  hWnd, ( (HMENU)ID_ANGLE_TB ), NULL, NULL );

    break;
    ///////////////////////////////// End Create Controls ///////////////////////////////////

    /////////////////////////////// User Actions On Controls ////////////////////////////////
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        //************************* Case statments tried in attempt to get the text box to 
        //************************* clear upon clicking on it and still have it usable afterwards
    //case ID_VELOC_TB:
        //  SendMessage( hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, ( (WPARAM)hWnd ), ( (LPARAM)hTextBoxVeloc ) );
//          SetWindowText( hTextBoxVeloc, (LPCSTR)blankBox[1] );
        //SetWindowText( hTextBoxVeloc, blankBox.c_str() );
        //GetLastError();
          //break;

        //  /*case WM_SETTEXT:
        //  SetWindowText( hTextBoxVeloc, TEXT( "" ) );
        //  break;
        //****************************************************************************************

    }
    // End user control action
    break;

//case WM_SETTEXT:
//  SetWindowText( hTextBoxVeloc, TEXT( blankBox.c_str() ) );
//  break;

case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    } break;
}

return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
}
```

Again, all of this runs fine aside from SetWindowText. I can input anything I want into the text box up to 10 chars (I think that's the limit I put), I can take that input and run it through a function to check if it is numbers or not, I can validate that input in that function and plug it into the variables to run the game, I just cannot get the SetWindowText to work with either text box. Since the original post I have also tried non-empty strings and I noticed that it doesn't input what I give it to input. When I click on the text box (which is the even I want to trigger the SetWindowText) it clears the text box's contents like it is working but then it doesn't add anything to its contents and breaks the text box and the game although the game only breaks once I try to do another input, it will continue to run up to the next input I try.

Comment: -1 Post is way too long. Please just post as short a complete program as possible that causes the problem. It will be easy to solve then.

Comment: I know it's really long, sorry about that. I have been scorned for not putting all the code before so I figured I would put all of it. Also since I am teaching myself Win32/DirectX I figured there might be a problem somewhere else I am not seeing. I'll shorten it up.

Comment: You need to cut it down to the bare minimum. An SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

The `TEXT()` macro only works with literals, so statements like `TEXT( troopDistStr.c_str() )` are not valid.  Just pass `c_str()` as-is, it will either compile or it will not:

```
hStaticTxtBoxDistance = CreateWindow( ..., troopDistStr.c_str(), ... );
```

Likewise for `TEXT( (LPCSTR)blankBox[1] )`:

```
SetWindowText( hTextBoxVeloc, blankBox.c_str() );
```

`troopDistStr` and `blankBox` are declared as `string`, which uses `char` data, so such statements will compile only if `UNICODE` is not defined for your project, so that `CreateWindow()` maps to `CreateWindowA()` and not `CreateWindowW()` (the fact that you are calling `UnregisterClass()` without using `TEXT()` indicates that you are not compiling for Unicode).

**Update**:

`SendMessage( hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, ( (WPARAM)hWnd ), ( (LPARAM)hTextBoxVeloc ) )` is not valid, you are passing an HWND where a `char*` is expected. You likely meant to pass `velocEntered` instead of `hTextBoxVeloc`.

`SetWindowText( hTextBoxVeloc, (LPCSTR)blankBox[1] )` is not valid, you are type-casting a single `char` value to a `char*` pointer.  You need to use `&blankBox[0]` instead, but that will not work when `blankBox` is declared as `char[1]` since there is no room for a null terminator, and will work when `blankBox` is declared as `string` only if it is not empty.

`SetWindowText( hTextBoxVeloc, blankBox.c_str() )` will always work fine as long as `blankBox` is a valid `string` instance and not corrupted.

Comment: I originally started out not using the     TEXT() statement but I just went back and tried both the char array and the string without using the TEXT() statement and it still has the same errors.

Comment: Please update your question with the corrected code, then someone can look at it again and see what other errors it has.

Comment: The only thing I changed was taking out the TEXT statements but I'll make an edit